# Why does PackageManager.MATCH_ALL documentation say to use the flag with extreme care?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-package-managers

I am trying to use the following code: `packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_ALL)`

The [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager#MATCH_ALL) for MATCH_ALL state: "This flag should be used with extreme care."

I am just trying to see if an intent is resolvable. MATCH_ALL seems like the most obvious solution to do this, but why do the docs warn about using this flag? What are the dangers of using this flag and what should be the better alternative?